# Does the verb have to be conjugated for a sentence to be considered complete?

Tags: verbs, sentence-fragments

I was filling out a description box for a potential meeting with a contact, & I went to type the sentence:

"To have a follow up conversation about ____'s guest lecture."

Would that be considered a full sentence or a fragment?

Comment: Are you judging a note to self or the title of an appointment as a full sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a sentence fragment because it's missing a subject, verb, or both. Yes, "have" is a verb, but yes, it's a "to-infinitive" and is not the main verb of the sentence, so its conjugation doesn't have a bearing on the question.

Is that a problem? Not necessarily. The context is informal and the meaning is understood. The implied sentence is something like:

> [The reason for the meeting is] to have a follow-up conversation...

Comment: Great, it's much more clear. Thank you!